# Action ID in OpenERP

Tags: openerp-7

I am creating a button in openerp that will open the window to enter a product. I have created the button from the debug view  the action needed for the button is "product" but I have to write the ID of this action which i am not able to find.
Can any one help me out on this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I usually work directly in Python, so I'm not sure exactly how you will enter this information, but you need to use something like:

```
ref('full_name_of_button')
```